# Is there a way to create an internal keyboard without installing in the settings?

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

I'm building an app that store songs.
In this project I decided to differentiate any song by title, lyrics and chords.

My UX idea consists of write chords with a custom keyboard.

This keyboard have space button, enter button, backspace button and all 12 notes, and 4 segment controller for differentiate by:

```
segment 1 = ["C", "C#/Db", "D", "D#/Eb", "E", "F", "F#/Gb", "G", "G#/Ab", "A", "A#/Bb", "B"] //chromatic scale

segment 2 = ["No", "Maj", "Min", "Sus2", "Sus4", "5"] //type1

segment 3 = ["No", "6", "7", "Maj7", "add9", "9", "11", "13"] //type2

segment 4 = ["No","C", "C#/Db", "D", "D#/Eb", "E", "F", "F#/Gb", "G", "G#/Ab", "A", "A#/Bb", "B"] //bass note
```

(This is just a keyboard for the app, I don't want to install this in the device settings.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set your custom view as the [`inputView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618614-inputview) of your text view or text field.

Comment: thanks for your support. Are you suggesting to claim a collection view over the screen like a keyboard? if yes how to avoid to claim the standard keyboard?

Comment: When you set that property, the standard keyboard is completely replaced by the view you set, and you're responsible for handling events to make it behave as an input (e.g. add a C# when the C# key is tapped).